# Gulp-dest: Create folder only when needed

Tags: gulp

I have the following simplified code in Gulp

```
var $               = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var argv            = require('yargs').argv;

/* Check for --production flag */
var isProduction = !!(argv.production);

/* Copy images to the "dist" folder */
/* In production, the images are compressed */
gulp.task('images', function() {
  var imagemin = $.if(isProduction, $.imagemin({
    progressive: true
  }));

  return gulp.src('src/assets/img/**/*')
    .pipe(imagemin)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/live/img'));
});
```

At present, I get the `dist/assets/live/img` folder created even when `src/assets/img/**/*` is empty. Is there a way to modify the return statement so that the folder is only created when there is actually something to go into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was down to a buggy glob pattern elsewhere in the file that always selected and copied the 'dist/assets/live/img' folder every time.